# Arduino char showing as 2 characters

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, xbee

I'm writing the character `1` from a node.js XBee using the code `sp.write("1");` to my Arduino's XBee. Then on my Arduino's XBee I read it like this (inside a loop):

```
  if (XBee.available()) {
    do {
      r = XBee.read(); 
      Serial.print(r);
    } 
    while (r != -1);
```

And the input char `r` shows up as `1�` instead of just `1`. Why is this and how can I remove the added invalid character from the char? Also is this char now 2 chars, how does this work? Thanks.

EDIT:

Arduino code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// Global variables
int AnalogPin = A2; // has much less jumpy readings than A0 (maybe A0 slightly damage from overuse)
int ledPin = 13;
SoftwareSerial XBee(2,3); // RX, TX

// Setup
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(AnalogPin, INPUT);
  XBee.begin(9600);
  for (int i=0; i<100; i++) 
    Serial.print("\n"); 
  // Random ID
  Serial.println("Listening...");
}

// MAIN LOOP
void loop() {
  char r;
  // Allow data reception while waiting for handshake confirmation
  while (1) { 
      if (XBee.available()) {
        do {
          r = XBee.read(); 
          Serial.println(r);
        } 
        while (r != -1); 
      }
      delay(500);
        if (r == 'Q') {
          Serial.println(r);
          Serial.println();
          Serial.println("Turning LED OFF.");
          digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
          Serial.println();
          exit(1);
        }
       else if (r == '1') {
          Serial.println(r);
          Serial.println();
          Serial.println("Turning LED on.");
          digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
          Serial.println();
        }     
  }
} // end main loop
```

Node code:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var express = require('express');
app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var ON_DEATH = require('death');

    /* ------------- Connecting to Serial Port ---------------- */
    var portName = '/dev/cu.usbserial-AD01SSII',
    portConfig = {
        baudRate: 9600,
    };

    var sp;
    sp = new SerialPort(portName, portConfig);
    sp.on("open", function (err) {

        console.log("Sending LED on signal.");
        console.log("Ctrl+C: quit and send LED off signal.");
        sp.write('1');

        // Cleanup when termination signals are sent to process
        ON_DEATH(function(signal, err) {
            var death_msg = 'Q';
            sp.write(death_msg);
            sp.close();   
            console.log("\n\nSending reset signal to nodes.\n\n")
            process.exit();
        })
*/
  }); // end open
```

All I'm really trying to do here is turn an LED on and off when I start or end the node program. Maybe I'm just too exhausted to think straight.

Comment: In passing a `char` to Serial.println(), this code *cannot* produce the claimed output.

Comment: What happens now is it produces this: 1
�   (new line in between) So that the last r value is the invalid char instead of the 1 that I want it to be.

Comment: Maybe with what was originally there using Serial.print, but not with the code currently in your question using Serial.println it doesn't!

Comment: It really does.. I'm running it right now. Actually, I forgot to remove the comment ending thing. But besides that it's the same.

Comment: It produces it with a newline, which is not what your questions says.  **Your question must be accurate, literally at character level, if you want help**.

Comment: Sorry, someone else answered and then deleted, and I was kind of mid-edit.

Comment: I answered and deleted, after your edit invalidated that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```c++
 do {
      r = XBee.read(); 
      Serial.print(r);
    } 
    while (r != -1);
```

Think about it. Since you tested for `XBee.available()` you will have at least one iteration of this loop. And then you do a *second* read, **and** print it, before finding that the second character is -1.

You need to re-order your loop, or your tests. The second character will be what -1 looks like on your monitor.

---

A better loop would be:

```c++
  while (XBee.available()) {
      r = XBee.read(); 
      Serial.println(r);
  }
```

This is the standard way of looping and reading. You won't get -1 from the read here, because if something is available, you will get that something.

Comment: I think the -1 means nothing is coming in?

Comment: K i just removed all of the while loop and it works a bit. will keep playing with it.

Comment: That's right: -1 means no input.